# async and anonymous types

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

This method:

```
private async Task readFileInfo(string folderId)
```

Has a call to another method:

```
importCount = await VM.importVehicles(myXDoc);
```

Defined here: (note: I changed it from a for loop to a for each but I'm getting similar results).

```
public async Task<Int32> importVehicles(XDocument importXMLDocument)
{
    var Importedvehicles = from vehicle in importXMLDocument.Descendants("vehicle")
                           select new
                           {
                               VehicleName = vehicle.Element("VehicleName").Value,
                               VehicleYear = vehicle.Element("VehicleYear").Value,
                               Odometer = vehicle.Element("Odometer").Value,
                               LicensePlate = vehicle.Element("LicensePlate").Value,
                               OilWeight = vehicle.Element("OilWeight").Value,
                               OilQuantity = vehicle.Element("OilQuantity").Value,
                               OilFilterModelNumber = vehicle.Element("OilFilterModelNumber"),
                               AirFilterModelNumber = vehicle.Element("AirFilterModelNumber"),
                               OilChangedDate = vehicle.Element("OilChangedDate"),
                               OilChangedOdometer = vehicle.Element("OilChangedOdometer"),
                               NextOilChangeDate = vehicle.Element("NextOilChangeDate"),
                               NextOilChangeOdometer = vehicle.Element("NextOilChangeOdometer"),
                               SettingDistance = vehicle.Element("SettingDistance"),
                               SettingMonths = vehicle.Element("SettingMonths"),
                           };

    Int32 vehicleId;
    vehicleId = await getMaxVehicleId();
    try
    {

        foreach (var item in Importedvehicles)
        {
            vehicle myImportedVehicle = new vehicle();
            myImportedVehicle.VehicleId = vehicleId += 1;
            myImportedVehicle.ImagePath = "Assets/car2.png";
            myImportedVehicle.VehicleName = item.VehicleName;
            myImportedVehicle.VehicleModel = item.VehicleName;


            myImportedVehicle.VehicleYear = short.Parse(item.VehicleYear);
            myImportedVehicle.CurrentOdometer = Convert.ToInt32(item.Odometer);
            myImportedVehicle.LicensePlate = item.LicensePlate;
            myImportedVehicle.LastOilChangedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.OilChangedDate.Value.ToString()).ToString("d");
            myImportedVehicle.LastOilChangedOdometer = (Int32)item.OilChangedOdometer;
            myImportedVehicle.ReminderDistance = (Int32)item.SettingDistance;
            myImportedVehicle.ReminderMonths = (Int32)item.SettingMonths;

            vehicleInformation myImportVI = new vehicleInformation();
            myImportVI.OilWeight = item.OilWeight;
            myImportVI.OilAmount = item.OilQuantity;
            myImportVI.OilFilterNumber = item.OilFilterModelNumber.Value.ToString();
            myImportVI.AirFilterNumber = item.AirFilterModelNumber.Value.ToString();

            myImportedVehicle.vehicleInfo = myImportVI;
            m_vehicles.Add(myImportedVehicle);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }

        await SaveList();
        return Importedvehicles.Count();
    }
```

I'm getting an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

when I step through it the `iVehicle` is highlighted but then it goes directly to the for statement.  Then it errors as it looks as it hasn't gotten the results from `iVehicle` yet.

Comment: where are you actually returning anything?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `async/await`. I would wager that, due to the **deferred execution**, something is `null` in your query. Debug that first.

Comment: Post short, but *complete* example (one others can compile and run) of code that shows the issue.

Comment: Also, the problem most likely isn't with `async` *or* anonymous types.

Comment: I updated to a more complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't 100% answer your question, but it should give you a good start.

The reason the debugger jumps straight into the `for...loop` after the declaration of `iVehicle`, is because your query does not get executed when you declare it. Therefore, iVehicle at that point is not a collection of anonymous types.

When you call `.Count()`, the query is being executed and `iVehicle` is attempting to be turned into a proper collection of anonymous types. However, because something in the query (that is being executed after you call `.Count()`) is `null`, you're receiving an `NullReferenceException`.

You should start by verifying that both `importXMLDocument` and the return value from the call to `Descendants()` is not null.

Hope that helps anyway.

**EDIT:**

Now that you've given a complete example, you have heaps of places that could potentially be `null`.

Each time you use this:

```
vehicle.Element("SomeElementNameHere")
```

That could potentially be `null`. Then you're calling the `.Value` property on a `null` object.

You need to make sure each element is definitely there. Isolate each case, and determine which one is `null`.

Comment: I checked both the importXMLDocument and the Desendants are returning values.

Comment: Now that you have given a proper example, you should definitely make sure each and every element is there. I will update my answer with what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your code like this:

```
var query =
    from vehicle in importXMLDocument.Descendants("vehicle")
    select new { ... };

var  iVehicle = query.ToArray();

for (var i = 0; i <= iVehicle.Count(); i++)
{
    ...
}
```

You need to force the evaluation of the query. That's what the `.ToArray` is doing. The query itself is only the definition of the query, not the results.

Comment: Why would not calling `ToArray()` cause `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - Calling `Count()` would cause evaluation, but it would be independent of the evaluation within the loop. Iterating a sequence can have side-effects so it is best to avoid multiple iterations.

Comment: @svick - I have no idea - the only code we got from within the loop is `...`. We'd need more information to answer that. I just commented on the flaw I could see in the code as provided.

Comment: @Enigmativity Aren't you still doing that though by calling `.Count()` on the array you've created?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - The query isn't an array until `.ToArray()` is called. Calling `.Count()` on the query evaluates it, but it doesn't create the array. The query remains a query and doesn't somehow become populated with the results.